# Problem installing mathabx-type1 font on Ubuntu-Linux

Tags: fonts

I've been trying to install the mathabx-type1 font with no sucess on my Ubuntu-Linux distribution. I downloaded the .pfb and .map files from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/mathabx).

What I did was the following:

1. First, I had to find where my local `texmf` folder was. In my case,
   it is located at `/usr/share/texmf`.
2. I created a folder named `mathabx-type1` on `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/`, and copied the .pfb files there.
3. I created a folder named `mathabx-type1` on `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/`, and copied the .map file there.
4. I ran the command `mktexlsr` on terminal.
5. I ran the command `updmap-sys` on terminal.

The thing is that the update at step 5 doesn't touch the `mathabx-type1` folder, but it does update the other folders on the same folder! (that is, it "sees" all the .map files in every folder at `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/` **except for mathabx-type1**). Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: As HO said, just use `updmap-sys --enable Map=mathabx.map`.

Answer (score 5):

The following step is missing between 4. and 5.:

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=mathabx.map
```

And before 4. the TeX files `CTAN:fonts/ps-type1/mathabx/texinputs/*` are copied to `texmf/tex/latex/mathabx/`.

You need also the MetaFont sources. `CTAN:fonts/ps-type1/mathabx/sources/*` are copied to `texmf/fonts/sources/public/mathabx/*`. Then the `TFM` files should be generated automatically if needed.

Remarks:

- Is your Ubuntu/TeX Live so old that it does not contain `mathabx` (date on CTAN is 2005)?
- External packages should not be installed in the distribution tree (`/usr/share/texmf` looks pretty close to a distribution tree). The next update of the distribution might interfere. A good place (for system-wide installation) is the "local texmf tree", that is the tree that is found by TEXMFLOCAL:

  kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL

Further reading: [**Installing TeX fonts**](http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html).

Comment: No, my TeX live distribution DOES contain mathabx, it doesn't have mathabx-type1, which are apparently neccesary to use Tex fonts in the PyX python packages. I'll give a try at your solution and post if it worked here. Thanks ;-).

Comment: The Type1 fonts for mathabx were introduced in TeX Live 2010. So it seems to be the well known problem of Ubuntu that still provides TeX Live 2009 by default.